# Jquery get parent of li href

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to get the parent of this li

```
     <li><a href="/panasonic/index.php/en/site/wheretobuy" class="WTB"></a>
        <ul>        
    <li><a href="/panasonic/index.php/en/showroom/index" id="myid" > testing</a> </li>    
       </ul>    
   </li>
```

How can I get the parent href of "myid".

All I have is this

```
document.write($('#myid').parent('li').find('a').attr('href'));
```

Which displays ".../showroom/index", I use document.write() just to test.

I want it to display ".../wheretobuy" and it has to be accessed via "myid"

here it is here

http://fiddle.jshell.net/86powers/YLYxF/

Thanks

Comment: You can use `console.log( text );` to output text if you have firebug in Firefox or use the Chrome Web Inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#myid').closest('ul').parent().find('a').attr('href')
```

This should work.